# Why is posting an image to Facebook with Sharekit so slow?

Tags: ios, facebook, performance, sharekit

I've a universal iOS app that uses ShareKit to share an image and a line of text:

```
SHKItem *item = [SHKItem image:imageToShare title: shareTitle];
if (destination == K_FACEBOOK) {
  [SHKFacebook shareItem: item];
}
```

The image is a UIImage of not more than 512 x 512, and the line of text is < 200 characters, so the total payload is ~50k.  When I share to email or twitter it's near instantaneous, but when I share to Facebook, it can end up taking somewhere between 20-30 seconds.

In my configuration for the Facebook sharer I've disabled using the Facebook app and Safari, so everything is presented by ShareKit itself.

Is there something that different in the process for uploading to Facebook that could cause this delay?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with Sharekit, but one reason it might take longer for Facebook to upload a picture is Facebook themselves. They might be restricting the amount of data that can get sent to it's servers, similar to what Apple does. Try testing the app with a very small image and see if it speeds it up. Then you know that it is not on your end.

Comment: I can confirm this to an extent on a similar issue with Facebook's uploading times (on differents apps).

Comment: Disregard of the image size it always takes 2 to 5 minutes to upload, the problem must be somewhere in the sharekit code, and I would love to know where.

Comment: Hmm... Well, I haven't used Sharekit so I guess I can't help. I will suggest reading through all documentation or Google the problem. You might want to try searching here   https://github.com/ideashower/ShareKit/issues

Comment: Agree with Whiteeagle (and thanks for adding the bounty) -- the process seems to take an inordinate amount of time whether the file is 200k or 2 megs.  The latter takes a bit longer, but the extra time is commensurate with a file transfer of that size.

Comment: Did you check the link I gave you above?

Comment: I read the documentation and all the issues, from both sharekit and sharekit 2, in the past. It wasn't much help. The problem relies somewhere in the internal processing, not on the requests made to facebook, but I cannot identify where.

Comment: It does seem like a problem from Sharekit itself. It will probably take a lot of work to fix it. Have you tried emailing Sharekit about the issue? Perhaps they can help diagnose the problem.